# Spark: HDFS Self-suppression not permitted

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am getting HDFS errors

```
Self-suppression not permitted, Failed to replace a bad datanode on the
existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try
```

when I run Spark process on top of a 4 machines cluster. HDFS is Yarn managed, but Spark runs with own cluster (so not managed by YARN).

It happens at around 80% of the process done.

Does it suggest that HDFS is "too slow" for Spark?

**UPDATE**

Potential solution that I am trying now is adding the below XML snippet to hdfs-site.xml:

```
    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy</name>
        <value>ALWAYS</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.best-effort</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: I tried with the above setting, but still getting the above error. Can you confirm if this solution worked for you or how did you fixed it.